# Erro ao conectar PHP ao SQL Server via ODBC Linux

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux, odbc

Estou fazendo uma conexao no no windowns via php ao SQL SERVER e esta indo normal, em uma maquina onde o servidor php é linux esta dando o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found' in /var/www/html/sql/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/sql/index.php(8): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={SQ...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/sql/index.php on line 8
```

Como habilito o driver `odbc` no linux ?

LINUX:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

APACHE:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 28 2015 14:05:48
```

SQL:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit)
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
NT x64
10.0.2531.0
```

PHP:

```
PHP Version 5.6.22-0+deb8u1
```

Comment: Quais as versões dos seus ambiente? Vá em [edit] e inclua essas informações na pergunta

Comment: @gmsantos editei,veja se é as informações que você precisa

Comment: versão do PHP ?

Comment: @gmsantos Inserido na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Primeiro, dê uma olhada nas permissões nolibsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0, para ver se o apache pode escrever e ler.

2) É necessário ver as dependências da lib e ver se não existe alguma faltando.

ldd /opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0

3) Se você está usando CENTos tente desabilitar o SELinux.